# How do you redo the manual merge of just one file in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge

When I perform a merge in mercurial with a number of manual conflict resolutions, sometimes I realize before committing that I've made a mistake in one or two of the files.  Short of starting over and redoing the whole merge, how can I tell mercurial to pop up the merge tool for a single file to let me redo the manual conflict resolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it hard to figure this out from the mercurial help and google.  I eventually got it by trial and error, though, and thought I'd post what I learned here.

To re-resolve a single file requires a two-step process:

```
hg resolve -u <file>
hg resolve <file>
```